# redefining the 'POST' post-type slug with register_post_type_args

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am trying to redefine the properties of the default post type 'POST'. I'm trying with the function register_post_type_args.

I want to redefine the label of the post type from "article" to "blog" and i want to add the slug "blog" for this post type in his url (*mysite/blog/my-post*)

Here is his call in functions.php:

```
function post_to_blog ($args, $post_type) {
    if ('post' !== $post_type) {
        return $args;
    }

    $args ['label'] = 'Blog';
    $args ['rewrite'] = array ('slug' => "blog", 'with_front' => true);
    return $args;
}
add_filter ('register_post_type_args', 'post_to_blog', 1, 2);
```

The label property is correctly redefined. The label is changed in the back office.
But the post slug is not taken into account. The url of my posts is still *mysite/name-of-post* and not *mysite/blog/name-of-post*

(I can't add the slug in settings / permalinks because I need to keep the default url type for other post types).

I think I do it with **register_post_type_args** but I don't understand why the slug is not taken into account. Do you have an explanation ?

EDIT :

Just out of curiosity, I tried to redefine the post with **register_post_type**. This is not the correct method, but with this solution, the URLs are correctly redefined.

```
register_post_type( 'post', array(
    'label' =>  'Blog',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => "blog/", 'with_front' => true),
));
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo but `if ('post'! == $post_type)` should produce a parse error. If this is your actual code then your function is probably failing silently because your error reporting is turned off. Remove the superfluous space `if ('post' !== $post_type)` and try again.

Comment: oops, just a mistake of copy paste in the question. I have the correct syntax in functions.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I come back on this problem because it seems that there is no solution with **register_post_type_args**.

In fact, it seems that it is impossible to redefine some default post-type properties. It is possible to modify some such as the Label. But slug is one of the properties that can not be changed.

For my permalinks problem, I was forced to use the permalinks settings in the back-office, and solve that problem in another way.

The function **register_post_type_args** however works perfectly with a custom post type. Which can be completely redefined.

This may eventually help some.